# Why does closing channel in go routine causes receiving channel to receive value?

Tags: go

I have a go routine that periodically polls every interval and does a action. It also checks for done channel, as a end signal, to stop the polling.

```
  go func(){
       for {
          select{
              case <-myticker.C:
                 do_something()
              case <-done:
                 fmt.Println("I am done")
                 return
         } 
       }

    }
```

I realized that if I close the channel, It also runs as if the value is passed to done channel, It prints out "I am done" Why is that so?

Comment: In this context (closing the `done` channel) it makes perfect sense. But if there is a need for checking the end of data, the `val,ok := <-ch` should be used and the `ok` flag be checked.

Comment: "Why is that so?" Because the language spec says it must be so. Are you asking what you can do with that language feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the spec:

> A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed
>   immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any
>   previously sent values have been received.

See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator.

Comment: Also `yields an additional untyped boolean result reporting whether the communication succeeded. The value of ok is true if the value received was delivered by a successful send operation to the channel, or false if it is a zero value generated because the channel is closed and empty.`

Answer (score 4):

Because it can't finish without returning values. So it has to return some "stub", according to spec zero value was chosen. 
Also you may use two-value form to check whether real value was returned or a stub.

```
val, ok := <- someChannel
if ok {
   // value was got from the channel
}
if !ok {
   // channel was closed
}
```